# Задать в ячейках границы диапазона суммирования

Tags: excel, excel-формулы, google-spreadsheet

Есть формула для суммирования:

```
=SUM(G1:G2)
```

Как вставить границы диапазона в такую формулу *Google Sheets*?

Пример:

в ячейке *B9* содержится значение начального диапазона для подсчёта суммы (301).

в ячейке *C9* содержится значение конечного диапазона для подсчёта суммы (402).

Формула должна посчитать значения

```
=SUM(G301:G402)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для **Excel** это будет выглядеть так:

```
=СУММ(ДВССЫЛ("G" & B9):ДВССЫЛ("G" & C9))
```

Для **Google Sheets** соответственно:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("G" & B9):INDIRECT("G" & C9))
```

Answer (score 0):

Варианты:

```
=СУММ(ДВССЫЛ("G" & B9 & ":G" & C9))
=SUM(INDIRECT("G" & B9 & ":G" & C9))

=СУММ(СМЕЩ(G1;B9-1;;C9-B9+1))
=SUM(OFFSET(G1;B9-1;;C9-B9+1))
```

Но применять *ДВССЫЛ/INDIRECT* или *СМЕЩ/OFFSET*, если есть адекватная замена, не советую - эти функции летучи: пересчитываются при любом изменении на листе. А *ДВССЫЛ/INDIRECT* ко всему прочему еще и медленная. Это все лишние вычисления.

Реальный пример: одна летучая *СЕГОДНЯ/TODAY*  подвешивала файл, т.к. от нее зависело много формул с нелегкими вычислениями. Заменили формулу на вставку даты макросом - файл начал "летать".

*ИНДЕКС/INDEX* - одна из самых быстрых в *Excel*

```
=СУММ(ИНДЕКС(G:G;B9):ИНДЕКС(G:G;C9))
=SUM(INDEX(G:G;B9):INDEX(G:G;C9))
```

Такая формула условно летуча - пересчет только при открытии файла, т.к. программе нужно определить динамический диапазон. В дальнейшем формула пересчитывается, как и положено - только при изменении входных данных.